# Convert Stream<List<Integer>> to IntStream using flatMapToInt() method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, java-11

Example:

```
System.out.println("----flatMapToInt----"); 

Stream<List<Integer>> list = Stream.of( 
    Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4), 
    Arrays.asList(10,20,30,40)
); 
IntSteam list2 = list.flatMapToInt(...);
```

How to achieve it using Java 8 or Java 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this: `IntStream intStream = list.flatMapToInt(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(i -> i));`

Answer (score 1):

It would be more readable to apply a combination `flatMap()` and `mapToInt()`, than use `mapToInt()` nested into `flatMapToInt()`:

```
Stream.of(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4), List.of(10, 20, 30, 40))
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
    ... // other operations
```